# Azure AD B2C Group Membership Custom policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, group-membership

Our current b2c custom policy extension property (where we store permissions) is limited to 255 characters. Therefore, we hit the limit of permissions and we need to expose AAD group memberships through Azure B2C Custom policy.
How do we define the custom claim to expose group memberships of the current user in a token?

Answer (score 0):

Either use this [sample](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/relying-party-rbac), which will present the groups in a better format in the token, but requires an API you have to host.

Or call the MS Graph directly from the Custom Policy as follows:

1. Get a token from AAD with `user.read` scope:
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/secure-rest-api#using-oauth2-bearer

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="SecureREST-AccessToken">
  <DisplayName></DisplayName>
  <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://login.microsoftonline.com/your-tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token</Item>
    <Item Key="AuthenticationType">Basic</Item>
     <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Form</Item>
  </Metadata>
  <CryptographicKeys>
    <Key Id="BasicAuthenticationUsername" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_SecureRESTClientId" />
    <Key Id="BasicAuthenticationPassword" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_SecureRESTClientSecret" />
  </CryptographicKeys>
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="grant_type" DefaultValue="client_credentials" />
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="scope" DefaultValue="user.read" />
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="bearerToken" PartnerClaimType="access_token" />
  </OutputClaims>
  <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

2. Then make a call to MS Graph:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-rest-api-claims-exchange

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile#metadata

```xml
        <TechnicalProfile Id="REST-GetGroupsFromMSGraph">
          <DisplayName>revoke my refresh token</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ServiceUrl">"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{objectId}/memberOf?$select=id"</Item>
            <Item Key="AuthenticationType">Bearer</Item>
            <Item Key="UseClaimAsBearerToken">bearerToken</Item>
            <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Url</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="bearerToken"/>
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="groupsPayload" PartnerClaimType="value" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

The claim `groupsPayload` will contain the value:

```json
[
    {
       "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.group",
       "id": "34af9ff3-ebfc-4bfb-9417-a86f5f499845"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.group",
      "id": "7485108c-7715-49af-a296-ee1f7295958d"
    }
]
```

And the token will have the claim, including the escape characters, as follows:

```json
"groupsPayload": [ "{ \"@odata.type\": \"#microsoft.graph.group\"", " \"id\": \"e06f5fd8-aee1-4e14-a692-dcde772c1465\" }" ],
```

Comment: Your example helped me define the custom policy, but I am having trouble receiving graph api response, application insights is catching a System Exception with error message: an internal error has occurred

Comment: How have you defined the groupsPayload datatype. if I use StringCollection I get a empty array, if I use string we get a system exception

Comment: `groupsPayload` should have a dataType of `stringCollection` in the `claimsSchema`. Make sure if you run the request in POSTMan or via Graph Explorer website, that the user is returning a group claim, and the JSON has key `value`.

Comment: I have changed the datatype to StringCollection and I am making the request from the custom policy.
My app insight log shows:
"groupsPayload": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]"
My graph api response:
{ "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#directoryObjects(id)", "value": [ { "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.directoryRole", "id": "1118fd14-0d58-5555-ad95-55467bb17444" }, { "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.group", "id": "111132ae-6244-5555-aeb1-2b11b048a444" } ] }
When the token is received the groupsPayload is an empty array... []

Comment: @JureFadiga - would it be possible to post your policy xml file after removing any identifying text? I am trying to do similar and want to include the orchestration steps and such and the documentation is not all clear on what this needs to be. Thanks in advance!